# Switching the position of two sections of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of integers representing a deck of cards with 52 cards in it, with numbers ranging from 1-52 to represent the cards. I am trying to write a method which will take two positions within the array as parameters to divide the array into three blocks. Block 1 is all the values below the first position, block 2 is all the values lying between the two positions(inclusive of the values at position 1 and 2) and block 3 is all the values lying above the second position. I then want to switch the positions of blocks 1 and 3 within the array.

So for an array with the values of:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12

Setting positionOne(1), positionTwo(9) would give the array:

11,12,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1

Here's what I have so far, which almost works but I think has bugs in it:

```
public void switchPositions(int pos1, int pos2) {
int[] newCards = new int[cards.length];
int sizeChunkA = 0;
int sizeChunkC = 0;
int sizeChunkB = 0;
int counter = 0;
for(int i = pos2+1; i<cards.length; i++) {
    sizeChunkC++;
   }
for(int i = 0; i<pos1; i++) {
    sizeChunkA++;
   }
for(int i = pos1; i<=pos2; i++) {
    sizeChunkB++;
   }
for(int i = 1; i<=sizeChunkC; i++) {
    newCards[counter] = cards[pos2+i];
    counter++;
}
for(int i=pos1; i<=pos2; i++) {
    newCards[counter] = cards[i];
    counter++;
    }

for(int i=0; i<sizeChunkA; i++) {
        newCards[counter]  = cards[i];
    counter++;
} 
cards = newCards;
```

}

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you interesting in algorithm that do it without external temporary array?

Comment: Hi dave! have you seen my answer? please mark it as correct if it helps you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of loops use `Arrays.copyOfRange` and `System.arraycopy`:

```
// make a copy of the first section before overwriting it
int[] copy = Arrays.copyOfRange (inputArray, from, to);
// overwrite the first section with the second section
System.arraysCopy(inputArray, sourcePosition, inputArray, from, copy.length);
// copy the original content of the first section to the second section
System.arraysCopy(copy, 0, inputArray, sourcePosition, copy.length);
```

You have to change the indices according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it this way.

Create three arraylists for your three temp blocks.

Iterate through your array starting at 0-> position 1. Moving the values into your first array list.

Iterate through your starting at position 1 and ending at position 2. Moving all values into the sec0nd array list.

Then iterate through your array starting at position 2+1 through to the end.

Combine the three array lists.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit clearer of a way to do this. If you want to code it yourself rather than just use the existing Arrays.copyOfRange (perhaps if you would like to do it in place rather than generating a new array).

```
int lengthOfDeck = cards.length;
int[] newCards = new int[lengthOfDeck];
for (int i = 1; i <= lengthOfDeck; i++) {
  if (i >=pos1 && i <=pos2) {
     newCards[i-1]=i;
  }
  else if (i < pos1) {
    newCards[i-1]= i + pos2;
  } 
  else {
   newCards[i-1] = i - pos2;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about approach without using additional memory?!

Main idea, is that if you want to shift array to the `offs` positions right or left you can do it in place with `2 full for loops`. I give you example:

1. Initial array `{1,2,3,4,5}`; we want to move it 2 positions right (i.e. `offs=2`), and have result `{4,5,1,2,3}`
2. **1st loop** for reverse all elements: `{5,4,3,2,1}`
3. **2nd loop** for reverse first `offs` elements: `{4,5,3,2,1}`
4. **3rd loop** for reverse other elements: `{4,5,1,2,3}`.

That's all! To solve your task, you have to do it twice, but second time you have to reduce array's length to not move last elements.

This is example:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
    replace(arr, 1, 9);
    // arr = [11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1]
}

public static void replace(int[] arr, int pos1, int pos2) {
    rotate(arr, arr.length, -pos1);
    rotate(arr, arr.length - pos1, -pos2);
}

// offs > 0 - to the right; offs < 0 - to the left
private static void rotate(int[] arr, int length, int offs) {
    offs = offs >= length ? length % offs : offs;
    length = Math.min(arr.length, length);

    for (int i = 0, j = length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        swap(arr, i, j);
    for (int i = 0, j = offs > 0 ? offs - 1 : length + offs - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        swap(arr, i, j);
    for (int i = offs > 0 ? offs : length + offs, j = length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        swap(arr, i, j);
}

private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
}
```

According to the **performance**. You have 4 full `for loops` with one swap in each of them. So performance is **O(n)**, without using additional memory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eran for his tip, here is a more adapted method for your needs:

```
public int[] splitArray(int[] i, int position1, int position2)  {

        position2++;

        int[] piece1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(i, 0, position1);
        int[] piece2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(i, position1, position2);
        int[] piece3 = Arrays.copyOfRange(i, position2, i.length);

        System.arraycopy(piece3, 0, i, 0, piece3.length);
        System.arraycopy(piece2, 0, i, piece3.length, piece2.length);
        System.arraycopy(piece1, 0, i, piece3.length+piece2.length, piece1.length);

        return i;

    }
```